How to Compare Binary Classifiers with Similar but Different Labels
I am interested in understanding the best way to compare two binary classifiers with similar but different labeling strategies. Here is the synopsis:
I am building a classifier to predict when a transaction a user makes will be declined based. Naturally, these declines lead to an account closure. The labels in Model 1 below are build off of these account closures.
However, in practice, this model now will have false negatives or allow transactions to pass that should have been flagged leading to revenue losses. An idea that I had for an iteration on the model (Model 2) is to also include the users who have led to revenue losses in conjunction with account closures.
My questions now are:

If there are any methods to compare the two classifiers? They are similar but in the end different due to the changed dependent variable.

One way I thought of comparing them is through the use of our manual queue. Before an account is closed it is inspected by a human manually. However, the observations in the queue are created by Model 1 and there are predictions Model 2 might send to the manual queue that Model 1 would not and vise versa. How can I reliably use this data?


Thank you in advance!

